# Chrome 37 has stopped showmodaldialog support.What is use instead of that?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, showmodaldialog

My web application is crashed after launched of `Chrome`new version(37 and above),since chrome has stopped the support of `showmodaldialog`.However i need  to implement same functionality in my web application.

I need some `return value` from popup same as `showmodaldialog`.I have designed all the popups page separately and called them from the parent page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing lots of googling , i have find out the solution of that issue.I am using `Jquery dialog` present in `jquery-1.9.1` version.The implementation of given below:

Add `jquery` library on `head` tag of the parent page

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Write the popup opening function,where i am creating a `div` and inside the `div` take `iframe` like this

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
 function Open() {

        var href = "../../PopUps/FindEmployee.aspx?Page=EC";
        var obj = $('<div id="divClose"></div>');

        obj.html('<iframe id="popUpFrame" style="border: 0px; " src="' + href + '" width="100%" height="99%"></iframe>');
        obj.dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            resizable: false,
            height: 500,
            width: 650,
            modal: true,
            title: "Find Employee",
            dialogClass: 'infoDialogHeader infoDialogTitle'
        });
        obj.dialog('open');
        return false;
    }
 function closeIframe() {
        $('#divClose').dialog('destroy');
    }


</script>
```

Now I am working on child page which is `FindEmployee.aspx` like ths:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("[id^=BtnReturnParentPage]").click(function (e) {
            var movedElement;

            if ($("#hdnInformationType").val() == "EC") { // condition for Employee Code                   
                movedElement = window.parent.$("[id*='txtECode']");
                // cleaning textbox
                movedElement.val('');
                movedElement.val($(this).parent().parent().find("[id^=gvEmployeeDetails_gvlblEmployeeCode]").text()); // assing relating information
            }

   window.parent.closeIframe();

        });

</script>
```

In above child page code , i have take value of `$("[id*='txtECode']")` `textbox` which is exist on parent page , and assign child page employee code value to parent page `textbox`.

So we need to create an element of `textbox` with name of `txtECode` on parent page so that assign the value of child page.

Hope it helps all the people who is struggling with `window.showmodeldialog`

Answer (score 0):

Chrome started to support <dialog> element.
Check this out. http://demo.agektmr.com/dialog/

Polyfill is available as well.
https://github.com/GoogleChrome/dialog-polyfill

Answer (score 0):

A simpler solution is this: instead of **window.showmodaldialog**, you can use **window.open** next to **window.opener.client_function**.

In this article by Peter A. Bromberg, it is very well explained: [ASP.NET Popup Windows With Return Values Redux](http://ASP.NET%20Popup%20Windows%20With%20Return%20Values%20Redux)

*"Less code, same operation"*