# Get values of Textbox in jquery Modal dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-dialog

I'm opening a view in jquery modal dialog like this

```
$("a.OpenView").on('click', function () {
       ></div>")
            .addClass("dialog closePopup")
            .attr("id", "popup1")
            .appendTo("body")
            .load("../../ControllerName/_partialView")
            .dialog({
                title: "LogIn",
                modal: true,
                height: "auto",
                minHeight: 260,
                maxHeight: 260,
                width: 450,
                left: 0,
                zIndex: 1001
            });

    });
```

Html

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
          <td align="center"><input name="" type="text" value="" title="User Name" class="width190" id="txtUserName" onfocus="txtFocus(this)" onblur="txtFBlur(this,'0')"/></td>
          <td align="center"><input name="" type="password" value=""  title="Password" class="width190" id="txtPassword" onfocus="txtFocus(this)" onblur="txtFBlur(this,'1')"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2" align="center"><input name="" type="submit" class="blue_btn" value="Sign In"  id="btnLogIn" onclick="javascript:return LogIn()"/></td>
        </tr>

      </table>
```

Now As soon as i close dialog once and then i reopen it again and enter username and password...I get `""` as value of both textbox...

What might be the possible reason for this, what i'm doing wrong?

LogIn function here

```
function LogIn() {
    var username = $('#txtUserName').val();
    var password = $('#txtPassword').val();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have 2 elements in the DOM with the same ID. 
Try destroy the dialog instead of closing it.

```
$("#popup1").dialog('destroy').remove()
```

Comment: any idea's how to destroy it?

Comment: $("#popup1").dialog('destroy').remove()

Answer (score 1):

Hey create `closeframe` function in parent page

```
function closeIframe() {
    $('#divClose').dialog('destroy');
}
```

and call that function from child page you can say `model popup`

```
window.parent.closeIframe();
```

For reference you can visit my [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25882950/chrome-37-has-stopped-showmodaldialog-support-what-is-use-instead-of-that)

Answer (score 0):

Try use the event "beforeClose" of the Jquery dialog

See more [Documentation here](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/)